# LINQ to SQL cannot connect to database, but the connection string is good

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, connection-string

I've deployed a MVC site and it's database to a web hosting provider. The default ASPNET tables and the applications custom ones share the same database. There are two connection strings in the web config, one for ApplicationServices and one for my LINQ to SQL dbml. As they share the same database then I use a identical connection string for both.

The application services functions seem to work as I can log into the site. However the return controller throws an exception because it's trying to use my data context this time. Identical connection string and yet it gives me the error:

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

This of course all works properly on my local machine. I would very much appriciate any suggestions as to why LINQ to SQL can't connect with a valid connection string.

Comment: Since the error indicates Names Pipes I suspect that Named Pipes is not supported in your hosting environment. How does connection string looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LINQ to SQL dbml file is inside a class library and the startup ASP.NET web project consumes this library as it's data layer. LINQ to SQL was reading it's connection string from the app.config of the class library when run through visual studio. When publishing the web project the dependent data library gets included but not it's app.config. I understand now that the fully qualified connection strings need to be manually copied into the web.config of the primary project where they override the defaults for the assembly. The problem I was facing was that with the absence of an app.config and no connection strings in the web.config, at least not fully qualified ones, the library was falling back to it's development defaults.

Comment: Dan has provided excellent inputs. With that, it is also worth notable that "DefaultConnection" key in web.config also has a working connecting string. That also can be a source of the problem.